# how to change the picture loaded into a (public static bitmapimage) when using the (Open File) more than once

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a public static bitmapimage that is used in an "Open file" dialog function.

First time picture loads normally.

```
globalValues.sourceBitmapImage.BeginInit();
globalValues.sourceBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@globalValues.sourcePicFileName);
globalValues.sourceBitmapImage.EndInit();
```

But when I try to use Open again I get an: (Cannot set the initializing state more than once.)

Now I understand that it's because I already used BeginInit, but I have no idea what to do about it. This is not just for display purposes. I'm using CopyPixels.

I would like to be able to change the picture I'm using if I use (Open file) again. It's static so I don't think I can delete it and I would like to be able to access the bitmapimage functions from anywhere in the program.

```
public class globalValues
{
    public static BitmapImage sourceBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
}
```

Comment: You can initialize it again to new instance of BitmapImage and then use it.

Comment: ...ok... that worked. Hmm I thought any BitmapImage needs a BeginInit but putting the new instance into the static one worked with multiple opens. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to edit BitmapImage multiple times, always initialize a new instance because bitmapImage object can be initialized with properties only once.